# Failed to compile ./node_modules/ipfs-http-client/src/add.js Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:24)

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg, ipfs

I am using ipfs-http-client@44.0.3 library to upload a file to IPFS. below is the error I am getting while compiling the code

[image]

I have also tried to reinstall the library with `sudo yarn add ipfs-http-client`. I even tried installing with npm package but i am still getting the same error.

Here is the Screenshot of add.js:
[image: Screenshot of add.js]

Comment: my Node version is v12.6.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a version of node that supports async generator syntax - v10 or above.

Also, https://discuss.ipfs.io is a great resource to get help with problems like this.

Comment: My Node version is 12 and it is not working with that version.